# "AttributeError: type" when attempting to write row data to csv

Tags: python

I have a script that runs a query on the google ads api then writes the results to a csv file. It works fine, but when I try to query the field `ad_group_ad.ad.type` I am getting attribute error: type.

First I open the csv and write a row of headers to it:

```
with open(ad_report_path, "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    headers = [
        "CampaignID",
        "CampaignName",
        "AdID",
        "Clicks",
        "CostMicros",
        "AdType",
        "FinalURLs",
        "Impressions",
        "Conversions",
        "CampaignStatus"
        ]
    writer.writerow(headers)
```

then I iterate through the rows of the object that the query returns, writing each row to my csv file.

```
for batch in stream:
    for row in batch.results:
        writer.writerow(
            [
                row.campaign.id,
                row.campaign.name,
                row.ad_group_ad.ad.id,
                row.metrics.clicks,
                row.metrics.cost_micros,
                row.ad_group_ad.ad.type,
                row.ad_group_ad.ad.final_urls,
                row.metrics.impressions,
                row.metrics.conversions,
                row.campaign.status
            ])
```

I am pretty sure that the field name is correct based on the google ads api documentation and the fact that when I query `ad_group_ad.ad.type` it returns a stream object without any errors. The issue is when I try to write the data to csv I am getting this attribute error: type. I have tried subscripting the row like `row.ad_group_ad.ad['type']` but the object is not subscriptable. Also I tried to call it like `row.ad_group_ad.ad('type')` but the object is not callable. I think this might be because `.type` is already reserved in python but I am not experienced enough to know.

This is the error message I get:

```
row.ad_group_ad.ad.type,
AttributeError: type
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including complete but minimal code, any example input, expected output, and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). You can [edit]. If you want more tips, see [ask].

Comment: `type` is not a reserved word, but it is the name of a builtin, so it's pretty common practice to use `type_` instead, even for attributes, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Wow I am dumb. So I ended up adding some print statements and learned the following. When you run the query the correct field name is `ad_group_ad.ad.type` however in the json object that gets returned the name is changed to `type_`. so when I write the rows I needed to say `row.ad_group_ad.ad.type_`